# Slide-in Call to Action div buggy on click and scroll down page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that on click will slide-in on the right but i am trying to also have it slide-in on scroll if it has not already been opened or open. So you can click the button to have it slide in or if closed as you scroll down he page it opens and then goes away after a few seconds or if button is clicked.

I sort of have it working but very buggy. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/50tab7vh/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="floating-form" id="contact_form">
<div class="contact-opener">CTA Box Toggle</div>    
    <div class="contact_body">

        <h3>This is a CTA Box</h3>
        <p>On click it will slide out and on scroll it will scroll out as you get down the page and then go away.</p>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> CTA Button</a>


    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var buttonhieght = $('.contact-opener').width()-52;
    var popdiv = $('#contact_form').width();
    var _scroll = true, _timer = false, _floatbox = $("#contact_form"), _floatbox_opener = $(".contact-opener") ;
    _floatbox.css("right", "-"+ popdiv+"px"); //initial contact form position
    _floatbox_opener.css("left", "-"+ buttonhieght+"px"); //initial contact form position

    //Contact form Opener button
    _floatbox_opener.click(function(){
        if (_floatbox.hasClass('visiable')){
            _floatbox.animate({'right': '-'+ popdiv+'px'}, {duration: 300}).removeClass('visiable');
        }else{
           _floatbox.animate({"right":"0px"},  {duration: 300}).addClass('visiable');
        }
    }); 
});
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var popdiv = $('#contact_form').width();
    var _floatbox = $("#contact_form");
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 700) {
        if (_floatbox.hasClass('visiable')){
            _floatbox.animate({'right': '-'+ popdiv+'px'}, {duration: 300}).removeClass('visiable');
        }else{
           _floatbox.animate({"right":"0px"},  {duration: 300}).addClass('visiable');
        }
    }
})
```

CSS:

```
/* floating box style */
.floating-form * { color: #fff; }
.floating-form {
    width:300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    background: #754c24;
    color: #fff;    
    right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: -2px -0px 8px rgba(43, 33, 33, 0.06);
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px -0px 8px rgba(43, 33, 33, 0.06);
    -webkit-box-shadow:  -2px -0px 8px rgba(43, 33, 33, 0.06);
    }
.contact-opener {
    position: absolute;
    text-transform:uppercase;   
    left: -100px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    top: 150px;
    background-color: #754c24;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: -2px -0px 8px rgba(43, 33, 33, 0.06);
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px -0px 8px rgba(43, 33, 33, 0.06);
    -webkit-box-shadow:  -2px -0px 8px rgba(43, 33, 33, 0.06);

}
#contact_form .contact_body { padding: 30px 30px 10px 30px; }
#contact_form .contact_body h3 { margin: 0rem 0 1.0rem; }
#contact_form .contact_body ol { padding: 5px 0px 10px 20px; }
#contact_form .contact_body li { padding: 8px 0px; font-weight: 700; }
#contact_form .contact_body .btn-primary { background: rgba(35,26,19,0.9); margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the scroll handler is never detached, so the `#contact_form` keeps showing/hiding until all the scroll events have been "cleared." I've updated your fiddle such that it only tries to display the `#contact_form` once when the page is scrolled past a certain point, and then the scroll handler is removed.

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/50tab7vh/3/

Comment: Wow this looks great! So i need to use those 2 plugins to accomplish this? Also any ideas why the clickable tab to make is slide out does not sit next to it? In my original i was trying to get the width dynamically and make it set the left negative margin so if i added more padding etc it would still keep it next to it and also adjust the negative right for the cta content box. Any way to keep this or not use plugins to do this?

Comment: There's only one library, TweenLite, being used for this. The other file is just a plugin that allows TweenLite to tween CSS properties. I just used those to demonstrate what needs to be done; if you're comfortable with some other tweening library, go ahead and use that.

Comment: Also, in the updated fiddle I see the tab next to it, and in the original I don't: http://imgur.com/a/Wg6NI Not sure why you don't see the tab next to it in the updated version.